# Having Trouble with tuples in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

i have this function:

```
pairs :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
pairs xs = zip xs (tail xs)
```

and i have to write another one, based on Pairs, that returns True if at least one pair of tuples is in an ascending order (e.g (2,3)).

here's my attempt at this:

```
unsorted :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
unsorted xs = [if fst x < snd x then True else False| x <- pairs xs]
```

why is this wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns a list of `Bool`s, not a `Bool`. You can use `any`:

```
unsorted xs = any (\x -> fst x < snd x) xs
```

or

```
unsorted = any (\(x, y) -> x < y)
```

if you want to use a list comprehension you can add a filter and then see if the resulting list contains any elements:

```
(length [x | x <- pairs xs, fst x < snd x]) > 0
```

or

```
(length [x | (x,y) <- pairs xs, x < y]) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a very clever way of solving this problem!

Comment: @user2876457: The second solution (without `any`) can be made even more clever by using `not (null [x|..])` instead of 'length [x|..] > 0', as the latter will traverse the entire list but the former will return as soon is it's found an element. This will make a difference when trying to evaluate `unsorted [1..]` for example!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the type error that GHC gives you should give you a hint about what the error is.

```
Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `[Bool]'
```

Your signature indicates that you want to a return a `Bool` but your implementation yields a list of `Bools`. To fix this use the function ( `any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool` ):

```
unsorted :: Ord a => [(a, a)] -> Bool
unsorted xs = any (\(a,b) -> a < b) xs
```

Comment: I need to use the function pairs in order to get a list of tuples and then check if the first element is smaller than the second one. if it is returns True else continues looking in the other tuples. it there aren't any in those conditions, returns false. can you help me with this ? because your function does not use pairs

Comment: The ``pairs`` function returns a list of tuples: ``[a] -> [(a,a)]`` and the ``unsorted`` function takes a list of tuples ``[(a, a)]``. Since this sounds like homework, I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to compose the two functions.

Comment: actually this is an exercise from last year's exam. and since i'm going to have one this year, i was trying to figure this out, but thanks anyway!